# define a variable in C (for example: #define PRE_WORD 1), then use that number later?

Tags: c

I have defined a set of states to categorize the text I want to analyse as follows:

```
#define PRE_WORT 0
#define IN_WORT 1
#define NO_WORT 2
#define WS_L 3
#define WS_T 4
#define BU 5
#define ZIFF 6
#define SONST 7
```

I then try to find out how many words, how many lines, longest word and longest line there are in the text, which is entered by the user and scanned via `getchar()`.

To count the characters in a line, I set the value of characters in line counter to 0 by

```
if (character=='\n') {
        line++;
        if (count_char_line>=char_line_max) {
            char_line_max=count_char_line;
            count_char_line=0;
                                    }
        else {count_char_line=0;}
```

Am I doing that right? Or am I just setting the state of `count_char_line` as `PRE_WORT`?

Comment: The states (#define) confuse me, but that "char_line_max" code looks like it should work.  What problems are you having?

Comment: Your question is unclear. You are not using any of the `macros` you have defined . Also your braces appear a bit mismatched.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson1.html) tutorial too

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answers and for the edit meagar. I now see where my mistakes where, the biggest problem was, that i tried to use the categories pre_state etc. in functions and envrionments where int were required. next time I'll also post the bits of code where i am actually using what i am refering to in my question. When Richard said, that my char_line_max code should work ok i knew where to look. Thank you thank you thank you

Comment: An enumeration type definition would be clearer: `enum state { pre_wort, in_wort, no_wort, ws_l, ws_t, bu, ziff, sonst };`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#define`s are simple replacements in the code. In your case you're setting a variable `count_char_line` to 0. What you did:

```
  count_char_line=0;
```

will work just fine. You could just as easily do:

```
  count_char_line=PRE_WORT;
```

They will result in the exact same thing as the compiler will come through and replace any instances of `PRE_WORT` with the number 0.

The only reason to pick one over the other is to make things clearer to those reading it, or if it's a value you use frequently in many places that could change (always good to have variables for hardcoded constants); but it's really up to you what to use.

---

As far as your code goes, it looks like it will do what you want (as far as I can tell what you're asking), but it's a bit overkill. When you have the same code in a `if` as you do in an `else` you can usually simplify it as such:

```
if (character=='\n') {
        line++;
        if (count_char_line>=char_line_max) {
            char_line_max=count_char_line;
        }
        count_char_line=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Any time you do a #define all it does is tell the compiler to look for that string and replace the string with whatever value follows. (there is more to it, read up about macros, but for your purposes now that's what it does)

So if by "setting the state" you mean "count_char_line == PRE_WORT" is true then yes. But after it's compiled that literally gets interpreted as "count_char_line == 0" so there really isn't much of a "state".

"#define" is useful to simply define some constants that mean something in a certain context. You haven't really defined the context it's used in so I'm not sure if you're doing it correctly or not, but at first glance that seems fine